# how to use again an actionEvent in Other textField in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a log in form that i was creating and i want the `TextField` `ActionEvent` to be used also in the `Button` but I don't know what to do. In Swing I've seen it that it can recycle an `ActionEvent` and use it in other like `TextField` but i don't know how to do it in JavaFX.

Here is a code for my `TextField` with an `ActionEvent`
and I want to apply this also to my `Button` so I dont have to create another method with just the same function but different Component. Thanks

```
 passField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
                {
                    if(admin.equals(userField.getText()) && password.equals(passField.getText()))
                    {
                        textInfo.setText("WELCOME "  + passField.getText());
                        textInfo.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    else
                    {                       
                        userField.clear();
                        passField.clear();

                        textInfo.setText("Incorrect username or password"); 
                        textInfo.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find a shared [`Event`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html) that both the [`Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) and the [`TextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) support.
In your example you are attaching a handler for a [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) watching for the `ENTER` key, which is equivalent to an [`ActionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html). luckily the [`Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) supports it too.

Create a shared [`EventHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html):

```
final EventHandler<ActionEvent> myHandler = e -> {
    if(admin.equals(userField.getText()) && password.equals(passField.getText())) {
        textInfo.setText("WELCOME "  + passField.getText());
        textInfo.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else {                       
        userField.clear();
        passField.clear();

        textInfo.setText("Incorrect username or password"); 
        textInfo.setTextFill(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Which you can now attach twice (or even more often):

```
button.setOnAction(myHandler);
passField.setOnAction(myHandler);
```

---

EDIT

Without lambda expression:

```
final EventHandler<ActionEvent> myHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
                if(admin.equals(userField.getText()) && password.equals(passField.getText())) {
                    textInfo.setText("WELCOME "  + passField.getText());
                    textInfo.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                }
                else {                       
                    userField.clear();
                    passField.clear();

                    textInfo.setText("Incorrect username or password"); 
                    textInfo.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly. btw can you put the code without lambda expression ? and how can i search or learn this kinds of code can you give me a link ? or reference? it means a lot to me thanks again :)))

Comment: is this the same as swing ?

Comment: @unknown No, this is JavaFX. So it should be JavaFX classes and imports.